# Git status upstream and downstream

Tags: git, git-branch, git-status

I can run these commands and get expected output

```
$ git branch --track test
$ git checkout test
$ touch hello.txt
$ git add hello.txt
$ git commit -m hello.txt
$ git status
On branch test
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.
```

However here is where my issue is

```
$ git checkout master
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

I want to know if I am ahead of `origin/master`, but I also want to know if I am
behind `test`. I am looking for a command to give me something like this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Your branch is behind 'test' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing built in, and tracking is stored only in the other direction: "X tracks Y", not "Y is tracked by ...", which is more complex as the "..." part can expand to more than one item.  (Also, I believe it's much more typical for Y to be a remote-tracking branch in the first place, in which case you can't ever be on Y—though a command that tries to find "what tracks Y" could certainly take arguments, so you could say "tell me about any of my branches that track `origin/master`).

That said, it's certainly possible to *build* such a thing.  The algorithm looks like this, in Python-esque pseudo-code:

```py
table = {}
for branch in local_branches:
    try:
        remote, tracked = get_what_branch_tracks(branch)
    except ValueError:
        continue # local branch "branch" not tracking anything
    try:
        br2 = analyze(branch, remote, tracked)
    except ValueError:
        warn('upstream for %s is gone' % branch)
        continue
    # at this point br2 is, e.g., origin/master or a local branch that "branch" tracks
    table.setdefault(br2, []).append(branch)

# now table[] is a table of branches that are tracked, with
# each table[key] being the branches that track branch "key"
```

So now for any interesting branch(es) that are in `table`, you simply count revisions find-able in the various branch pairs, the same way `git status` does, which in shell is just:

```sh
# to compute "git status" for branch X that tracks Y:
nahead=$(git rev-list --count Y..X) # we're ahead $nahead commits
nbehind=$(git rev-list --count X..Y) # and behind $nbehind
```

If you're behind but not ahead, you can fast-forward.

The details for `get_what_branch_tracks` are simply to do some `git config --get`s, of `branch.branch.remote` and of `branch.branch.merge`, while the details for `analyze` are more complex: if `remote` is `.` then whatever is in `tracked` is simple, but if it's an actual remote, whatever is in `tracked` must be passed through the corresponding `fetch` lines to find the appropriate remote-tracking branch.